# Trying to do a simulation in R

Tags: r, simulation

I'm pretty new to R, so I hope you can help me!
I'm trying to do a simulation for my Bachelor's thesis, where I want to simulate how a stock evolves.
I've done the simulation in Excel, but the problem is that I can't make that large of a simulation, as the program crashes! Therefore I'm trying in R.

The stock evolves as follows (everything except $\epsilon$ consists of constants which are known):
$$W_{t+\Delta t} = W_t exp^{r \Delta t}(1+\pi(exp((\sigma \lambda -0.5\sigma^2) \Delta t+\sigma \epsilon_{t+\Delta t} \sqrt{\Delta t}-1))$$

The only thing here which is stochastic is $\epsilon$, which is represented by a Brownian motion with N(0,1).

What I've done in Excel:

- Made 100 samples with a size of 40. All these samples are standard normal distributed: N(0,1).
- Then these outcomes are used to calculate how the stock is affected from these (the normal distribution represent the shocks from the economy).

My problem in R:

I've used the sample function:
`x <- sample(norm(0,1), 1000, T)`
So I have 1000 samples, which are normally distributed. Now I don't know how to put these results into the formula I have for the evolution of my stock. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just as an aside, you should probably look into using `rnorm` to generate normally distributed samples (such as: `rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=1)`.

Comment: That's True! But samples working last night. The problem is how i work with them?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but have you read any introductory material on R (there are many such introductions to be found by googling)? Your formula should not be hard to implement after reading a few pages of such an introduction. Have you tried starting with only part of the formula? I suggest that if after reading up you still have problems, you be a bit more specific about what exactly you are having problems with. Good luck.

Comment: Yes - i've used R in econometrics, but coding is not my strong side! When i first see a code i know how to use it, but I don't know how to modify or write my own code

Comment: The CRAN Task View for [Finance](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html) appears to include several packages with built-in simulation functions for this type of problem.

Comment: FWIW, this is a simple and small simulation that Excel will have no trouble with. Long ago I created much larger simulations (for options pricing) running on 25 MHz 486 Intel chips with a few MB RAM and they took almost no time to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using R for (discrete) simulation**

There are two aspects to your question: conceptual and coding.

Let's deal with the conceptual first, starting with the meaning of your equation:

**1. Conceptual issues**

The first thing to note is that your evolution equation is *continuous* in time, so running your simulation as described above means accepting a discretisation of the problem.  Whether or not that is appropriate depends on your model and how you have obtained the evolution equation.

If you do run a discrete simulation, then the key decision you have to make is what stepsize $\Delta t$ you will use.  You can explore different step-sizes to observe the effect of step-size, or you can proceed analytically and attempt to derive an appropriate step-size.

Once you have your step-size, your simulation consists of pulling new shocks (samples of your standard normal distribution), and evolving the equation iteratively until the desired time has elapsed.  The final state $W_t$ is then available for you to analyse however you wish.  (If you retain all of the $W_t$, you have a distribution of the trajectory of the system as well, which you can analyse.)

So:

- your $x$ are a sampled distribution of your shocks, i.e. they are $\epsilon_t=0$.
- To simulate the evolution of the $W_t$, you will need some initial condition $W_0$.  What this is depends on what you're modelling.  If you're modelling the likely values of a single stock starting at an initial price $W_0$, then your initial state is a 1000 element vector with constant value.
- Now evaluate your equation, plugging in all your constants, $W_0$, and your initial shocks $\epsilon_0 = x$ to get the distribution of prices $W_1$.
- Repeat:  sample $x$ again -- this is now $\epsilon_1$.  Plugging this in, gives you $W_2$ etc.

**2. Coding the simulation (simple example)**

One of the useful features of R is that most operators work element-wise over vectors.

So you can pretty much type in your equation more or less as it is.

I've made a few assumptions about the parameters in your equation, and I've ignored the $\pi$ function -- you can add that in later.

So you end up with code that looks something like this:

```
 dt <- 0.5   # step-size
 r <- 1      # parameters
 lambda <- 1
 sigma <- 1    # std deviation
 w0 <- rep(1,1000)   # presumed initial condition -- prices start at 1

 # Show an example iteration -- incorporate into one line for production code...
 x <- rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=1)  # random shock
 w1 <- w0*exp(r*dt)*(1+exp((sigma*lambda-0.5*sigma^2)*dt +
           sigma*x*sqrt(dt) -1))  # evolution
```

When you're ready to let the simulation run, then merge the last two lines, i.e. include the sampling statement in the evolution statement.  You then get one line of code which you can run manually or embed into a loop, along with any other analysis you want to run.

```
 # General simulation step
 w <- w*exp(r*dt)*(1+exp((sigma*lambda-0.5*sigma^2)*dt +  
           sigma*rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=1)*sqrt(dt) -1))
```

You can also easily visualise the changes and obtain summary statistics (5-number summary):

```
 hist(w)
 summary(w)
```

Of course, you'll still need to work through the details of what you actually want to model and how you want to go about analysing it --- and you've got the $\pi$ function to deal with --- but this should get you started toward using R for discrete simulation.

Comment: @user134142  Please note the correction -- the $x$ are the **random shocks**, not the $W$ states.

Comment: It's the first part of what you wrote i want to simulate. The point of the simulation is to discover if it's necesarry to rebalance your portfolio continously or once every quarter or year is enough (So i want to see the wealth loss)

I've done this so far:

x <- sample(rnorm(40, mean = 0, sd = 1), 1000, TRUE)
x

WT <- W0*exp(r*deltat)*(1+p*(exp((sigma*lambda-0.5*sigma2)*deltat+sigma*x*sqrt(deltat)-1)))

But id doesn't do this: Using W1 to calculate W2 and W2 to calculate W3 and so on...

Comment: @user134142: I've added code to the answer.  Not sure why you've still got `sample(rnorm)` ---  rnorm *is* the sampling operator -- it stands for sampling from a random normal.  (BTW, if you find the answer helpful, feel free to upvote it... ;)

Comment: @user134142: The key is `w0 <- rep(1,1000)` --- your prices have to be a vector of the same dimension as your shocks.  Obviously, you'll choose your initial price to be whatever you want -- I've set it to 1 for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the time you're using on this Assad!

But i won't work for me! It seems that your code is having a vector, where i calculate 1000 different ways the stock will evolve.

What i like it to do is to use the previous calculated price to calculate the next price. Ex. When t=1 the price is 1.1, then to calculate t=2 the W0 will be replace with 1.1 from t=1, so it might gives a price of 1.2. Then again to calculate the price in t=3, then the price of 1.2 is placed at W0.

The normal distribution is only used to make the shocks random.

Of course i'll upvote you!

Comment: The reason i use the sample function is because i want to do  ex. 1000 simulations and put them into a sample, where i use the end result to calculate the mean of

Comment: @user134142: Yes, that's pretty standard.  There is nothing in the above code that prevents you from doing this.  The idea is that you've now got a template that you can work from and modify it to do exactly what you need.  Good luck!